# Contractibility of a $K_0^{\oplus}$ presheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology

Let's assume $X$ is a smooth projective variety over a field. Let $\Delta^{\bullet}$ be the cosimplicial scheme over the same field, where at level $n$ is just the $n$-th algebraic simplex. We can define a simplicial abelian group $K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})$. My question: is $\Omega|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$ rationally (after tensoring with rational numbers) contractible? or at least rationally connected? ($\pi_1(|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|\otimes \mathbb{Q}=0$). I'd like to hear your thoughts on this, even if you think it should not be true or any ideas how to approach it.

**Background**

Here $K_0^{\oplus}$ is the direct sum $K$-theory, where only split exact sequence of vector bundles are declared to be exact. The space$\Omega|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$ appears as a cofiber in the following way:

$$|K(X\times \Delta^{\bullet},\mathbb{G}_m^{\wedge 1})|\rightarrow \Omega|K(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|\rightarrow \Omega|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$$
In the D. Grayson's [work](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.9304&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on weight filtration via commuting automorphisms.
The middle space is just $K(X)$ (which is the $K$-theory space). It can be proved that there is a homotopy equivalence between $|K(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$ and $|K^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$. So the map to the cofiber is just defined by taking level-wise $\pi_0$. Specially there is a surjection from $\pi_1(K(X))$ to $\pi_1(|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|)$.

The intuition behind my question is the space $|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$ is roughly the weight zero part of algebraic $K$-theory which is known to vanish, so it might be rationally contractible. Although this is intuitive, but more rigorously the space $|K_0^{\oplus}(U\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$  defines a presheaf which its sheafification is contractible (sheafification is an essential part of deriving motivic complex from this filtration), so in fact there is no need for the space $|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|$ to be contractible (it needs to be sheafified) but I do have some more rigorous reasoning that why $\pi_1(|K_0^{\oplus}(X\times \Delta^{\bullet})|\otimes \mathbb{Q}=0$ is most likely true.

**My approach**

I give a brief sketch of how I did approach the problem but failed. Our simplicial abelian group is equivalent to a chain complex by Dold-Kan and we just need to calculate its homology at degree one. You can actually calculate what the elements in the kernel should look like. It is simple but too long for here (You need a criterion by Heller on equality of two elements in the Grothendieck group and $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariance of $K_0$.). The elements of kernel are generated by $[V]-[W]$ where $V$ and $W$ are two vector bundles on $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$. Now to describe $V$ and $W$ you need to have three vector bundles $M_1,M_2$ and $M_3$ on $X$ with short exact sequences $SE1: 0\rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3 \rightarrow 0$ and $SE2: 0\rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3 \rightarrow 0$ such that $SE1$ and $SE2$ are non-isomorphic short exact sequence on the same objects. So the vector bundle $V$ is the deformation of $SE1$ to a split exact sequence and $W$ is the deformation of $SE2$ to a split exact sequence.
A situation that results for something like this to be zero could be existence of a vector bundle on $X\times \mathbb{A}^2$ (consider a triangle in $X\times \mathbb{A}^2$ such that each side is a $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$) where restriction of the vector bundle to two sides are $V$ and $W$ and to the third side is a symmetric vector bundle (one that by filliping left and right doesn't change for example the constant split extension of $M_1$ and $M_3$ along the line does satisfy it.). So inherently it is the problem of extending a vector bundle from closed sub-scheme to the whole scheme.

One fun fact is that on affine chart the extension exists and it is unique (by Bass-Quillen theorem for smooth algebras over a field). So the problem is extending the gluing maps.