# Non-isomorphic short exact sequences on isomorphic objects

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}\newcommand\SE{\mathrm{SE}}\newcommand\Def{\mathrm{Def}}$Assume $X$ is a smooth projective variety over a field. There are two non-isomorphic short exact sequence of vector bundles with isomorphic objects on $X$. Both of them are in the form $0\rightarrow N \rightarrow M \rightarrow P \rightarrow 0$. I'll be referring to one as $\SE1$ and the other one as $\SE2$. Since these two are non-isomorphic they correspond to different elements in $\Ext^1(P,N)$. Given two elements of the Ext group we can deform them to each other. Now consider the $\Def1$ which is a vector bundle on $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ that at time $0$ gives us the extension corresponding to $\SE1$ and at time $1$ gives us the extension corresponding to $\SE2$. $\Def2$ is defined in a similar way, but it is a vector bundle corresponding to deforming $\SE2$ to $\SE1$. Is it true that $\Def1\cong \Def2$?

I call $\Def2$ a flip of $\Def1$, because it is the same as $\Def1$ but mirrored such that $t=0$ and $t=1$ are transferred to each other.

My second question: is it possible to find a vector bundle on $X\times \mathbb{A}^2$ such that its restrictions to three lines in general position (by a line I mean a $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ inside $X\times \mathbb{A}^2$) are either $\Def1$ or its flip $\Def2$? (The three lines should make a triangle and vertices of this triangle are the corresponding points to times 0 and 1 described in paragraph 1.)

In case you are wondering where all these weird [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/users/127776/user127776?tab=questions) are coming from, [Contractibility of a $K_0^{\oplus}$ presheaf](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372723/contractibility-of-a-k-0-oplus-presheaf) is the source.